# How do I use the constructor in a javascript object to only use the properties in `this`?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to create an instance of the following class:

```
class Person {
    firstName;
    lastName;
    birthday;
    constructor(props: Person) {
        {firstName,lastName,birthday} = props
    }
}

var me = new Person({firstName: "donald", 
lastName: "trump",
 middleName: "john"})
```

I'd like the constructor to only select the properties of the class to assign to "this", so that `me` will be `{firstName: "donald", lastName: "trump", birthday: undefined}`

My idea would be to do this:

```
class Person {
    firstName;
    lastName;
    birthday;
    constructor(props: Person) {
        this.{firstName,lastName,birthday} = props
    }
}

var me = new Person({firstName: "donald", lastName: "trump", middleName: "john"})
```

or something similar.

Comment: `({firstName: this.firstName, lastName: this.lastName, …} = props);` would work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this in two lines:

```
const {firstName,lastName,birthday} = props;
Object.assign(this, {firstName,lastName,birthday});
```

Now, if this is only about *three* properties, just do:

```
this.firstName = props.firstName;
this.lastName = props.lastName;
this.birthday = props.birthday;
```

It is more readable, and slightly faster. Worth the extra line.

You can also change the constructor signature, so it destructures the desired properties:

```
constructor({firstName: string, lastName: string, birthday: Date}) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.birthday = birthday;
}
```

Comment: I ended up going with combination of first one and third one.  on the third one, constructor typing updated as: `constructor({firstName, lastName, birthday}: Person)` though.. Thank you!